# Unknown column 'id.state' in 'on clause'

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm getting this error can some help me?

Unknown column 'id.state' in 'on clause'

This is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `fam_crimes`.`id`, `starter_id`, `num_dlns`, `deelnemers`,  `state`, `state_id`, `misdaad` FROM `fam_crimes`
LEFT JOIN `gameStates` ON (`id`.`state`=`state`.`fam_crimes`)
WHERE `family_id`=".$famID." ORDER BY `id` ASC ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: which version of sqlserver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's re-write that for legibility.

```
$sql = mysql_query(
  "SELECT `fam_crimes`.`id`,
               `starter_id`,
                 `num_dlns`,
               `deelnemers`,
                    `state`,
                 `state_id`,
                  `misdaad`
   FROM `fam_crimes`
   LEFT JOIN `gameStates` ON (`id`.`state`=`state`.`fam_crimes`)
   WHERE `family_id`=".$famID." ORDER BY `id` ASC ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Now look at line 10 in there.  As @Kan says, there is no `id` table in the query.

So I'm going to make a guess!  Change line 10 to:

```
LEFT JOIN `gameStates` ON (`fam_crimes`.`state_id`=`gameStates`.`id`)
```

Good luck, and unless this answer was a very lucky guess, you'll have to post a description of your tables (What columns are in `fam_crimes` and `gameStates`?).

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be table name, `state` should be column name. There is no table `id` in the query.

I assume it should be something like:

```
SELECT `fam_crimes`.`id`, `starter_id`, `num_dlns`, `deelnemers`,  `state`, `state_id`, `misdaad`
 FROM `fam_crimes`
 LEFT JOIN `gameStates` ON (`gameStates`.`id`=`fam_crimes`.`state`)
WHERE `family_id`...
```

Comment: Now i get Unknown column 'fam_crimes.state' in 'on clause'

Comment: @user2668449 You should know better which column do you have in your tables. Show tables then.